# Using AWK to check whether a file name meets a given format

Tags: awk

Is there a way to check a filename using a program in AWK. So I need the code to check whether 2 files in same directory meet this format of naming

nppcase_***_*******header***************.csv

this will fail nppcaadese_***_*******bvdhistack***************.csv

this will pass nppcase_lpc_abc123_header_anychara.csv

so too clarify the * are any characters and the rest is literal.

And if the test was to fail the program should output a print statement then exit the program.

Comment: It is not clear, could you please do let us know if let's say we are passing 4 to 5 files to `awk` program and out of 5, 4 files are matchig the regex crieteria. So do you want to print their contents(4 matchinig files contents) or simply exit because 1 file name is not matching?

Comment: Why are you involving `awk`? That's trivial and appropriate for just shell alone. Post some examples though (some that do and some that don't pass the test) as it's not clear if the `*`s are literal or placeholders, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use ls and pipe that to awk on the command line with a regex.  Something like this would work. You will need to use the "." (regex wildcard) character instead of the "*".  You would also escape the last "." as you want a literal period as opposed to it being a wildcard.

```
ls | awk '{if ($1 ~ /nppcase_..._......header..............\.csv/) { print $0 " matches the format" } else { print $0 " does not match!"}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as your *format of naming* is unclear to me, I'll use simpler regex to match exactly three characters like `foo` and `bar`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<ARGC;i++)if(ARGV[i]!~/^...$/){print "statement";exit}}' foo file
statement
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    for(i=1;i<ARGC;i++)          # loop filenames given as parameters
        if(ARGV[i]!~/^...$/) {   # if filename does not match regex ...
            print "statement"    # print statement
            exit 1               # and exit with a non-zero value
    }
    exit                         # exit anyway
}' foo file                      # files you want to check
```

Answer (score 0):

Though as James sir said your file's format thing is not clear, could you please try following.(based on your question only).

```
awk 'FILENAME!~/nppcase_*_.*header.*\.csv/{print "Seems " FILENAME " is NOT following pattern so exiting now...";exit} 1' nppcase_***_******header**************.csv  nppcase_***_******header12131**************.csv
```

Logic for above code is simple, it will keep printing contents of a Input_file if it is matching regex if NOT then it will print a message on screen and exit from `awk` program.